# How can I remove cells containing NULL from a matrix consisting of a list and vectors?

Tags: r, list, matrix, null, cell

I would like to remove all cells, which contain NULL, from a matrix. However, the matrix consists of a list and vectors.
For example:

```
Col1<-list(NULL,2,3,4,5,NULL)
Col2<-c(0,2,3,4,5,0)
Col3<-c("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6")
cbind(Col1,Col2,Col3)
     Col1 Col2 Col3   
[1,] NULL 0    "Name1"
[2,] 2    2    "Name2"
[3,] 3    3    "Name3"
[4,] 4    4    "Name4"
[5,] 5    5    "Name5"
[6,] NULL 0    "Name6"
```

How can I remove cell 1 and 6 from the matrix?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If your matrix is called `mat` you can do `mat[rowSums(mat == "NULL") == 0, ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the matrix with string `"NULL"`, it returns logical value whether the cell is `NULL`.

```
mat <- cbind(Col1,Col2,Col3)
mat == "NULL"

#      Col1  Col2  Col3
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

You can use this to remove rows with `NULL`.

Using `rowSums` :

```
mat[rowSums(mat == "NULL") == 0, ]

#    Col1 Col2 Col3   
#[1,] 2    2    "Name2"
#[2,] 3    3    "Name3"
#[3,] 4    4    "Name4"
#[4,] 5    5    "Name5"
```

Or with `apply` :

```
mat[apply(mat != "NULL", 1, all), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `is.null`

```
mat[!apply(`dim<-`(sapply(mat, is.null), dim(mat)), 1, any),]
```

#### data

```
mat <- cbind(Col1,Col2,Col3)
```